# FastAPI with Redis pubsub

Tags: python, redis, fastapi

I am looking for a solution for using FastAPI with Redis pubsub without using threads. I have looked around for solutions using aioredis, redis-py and web sockets, but I can't seem to make them work.

Would love to have a simple example of a unicorn server running, while subscribed to a Redis channel, printing the message when receiving it. I am using Python3.6.12 so python3.6 solutions are preferred.

Thanks!

Below is the most recent try on aioredis without FASTapi, can't get the print message when publishing on the Redis in another terminal.

```
import asyncio
import aioredis
import async_timeout

STOPWORD = "STOP"


async def pubsub():
    redis = aioredis.Redis.from_url(
        "redis://:password@localhost:6379", max_connections=10, decode_responses=True
    )
    await redis.publish("channel:1", "abc")
    psub = redis.pubsub()
    async def reader(channel: aioredis.client.PubSub):
        while True:
            try:
                async with async_timeout.timeout(1):
                    # print("trying to get message")
                    message = await channel.get_message(ignore_subscribe_messages=True)
                    if message is not None:
                        print(f"(Reader) Message Received: {message}")
                        if message["data"] == STOPWORD:
                            print("(Reader) STOP")
                            break
                await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                pass

    async with psub as p:
        await p.subscribe("channel:1")
        await reader(p)  # wait for reader to complete
        await p.unsubscribe("channel:1")

    # closing all open connections
    await psub.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    result = loop.run_until_complete(pubsub())
    print('finished')
```

Comment: Can you show exwmples of what you tried?

Comment: edited to add something I am trying on aioredis. All solutions I tried either blocks on the Redis subscribe or the subscription cannot receive the messages.